# Tensorflow failed to run on k20m and k40m GPUs

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

I was trying to run Tensorflow on k40m GPU and got an error:

```
F tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:383] Check failed: CUDA_SUCCESS == dynload::cuCtxSetCurrent(context) (0 vs. 216)
```

The issued can be reproduced on k40m and k20m GPU: 
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/526

Anyone knows a fix?

Detailed log:

```
++ python cifar10_train.py
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:105] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so.7.5 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:105] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:105] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so.7.5 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:105] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so.4 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:105] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so.7.5 locally
Filling queue with 20000 CIFAR images before starting to train. This will take a few minutes.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:102] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: Tesla K40m
major: 3 minor: 5 memoryClockRate (GHz) 0.745
pciBusID 0000:08:00.0
Total memory: 11.25GiB
Free memory: 11.15GiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:126] DMA: 0 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:136] 0:   Y 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:718] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: Tesla K40m, pci bus id: 0000:08:00.0)
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:53] Creating bin of max chunk size 256B
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:53] Creating bin of max chunk size 512B
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:53] Creating bin of max chunk size 1.0KiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:53] Creating bin of max chunk size 2.0KiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:53] Creating bin of max chunk size 4.0KiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:53] Creating bin of max chunk size 8.0KiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:53] Creating bin of max chunk size 16.0KiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:53] Creating bin of max chunk size 32.0KiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:53] Creating bin of max chunk size 64.0KiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:53] Creating bin of max chunk size 128.0KiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:53] Creating bin of max chunk size 256.0KiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:53] Creating bin of max chunk size 512.0KiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:53] Creating bin of max chunk size 1.00MiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:53] Creating bin of max chunk size 2.00MiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:53] Creating bin of max chunk size 4.00MiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:53] Creating bin of max chunk size 8.00MiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:53] Creating bin of max chunk size 16.00MiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:53] Creating bin of max chunk size 32.00MiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:53] Creating bin of max chunk size 64.00MiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:53] Creating bin of max chunk size 128.00MiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:53] Creating bin of max chunk size 256.00MiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:107] Allocating 10.60GiB bytes.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:118] GPU 0 memory begins at 0x13047a0000 extends to 0x15aaa4019a
F tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:383] Check failed: CUDA_SUCCESS == dynload::cuCtxSetCurrent(context) (0 vs. 216)
./run.sh: line 4: 33880 Aborted                 python cifar10_train.py
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a [bug](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/526) in tensorflow.

It helps to set driver in EXCLUSIVE_PROCESS mode instead of EXCLUSIVE_THREAD:

```
 sudo nvidia-smi -c 3
```